# BIND DNS recursion only to my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am asked to allow recursion just to the clients belonging to an specific domain. I thought I could go to my `named.conf` and add in the options area this line:
`allow-recursion { myDomain ; };` 
but then I realized this was a huge mistake, is there any way to allow DNS recursion to the clients in my domain without having to write every IP address on the `allow-recursion{};` list?

Comment: How is "your domain" defined? Are there particular subnets? Remote roaming clients?

Comment: @thrig my domain is supposed to be a particular subnet. So maybe I can specify that subnet to be allowed to have recursion. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a particular subnet, then one can allow recursion via something like:

```
acl trustednets {
    # server itself
    localhost;
    # the subnet
    192.0.2.0/24;
    # any others... (BIND also has a "localnets" to trust
    # connected subnets, if that is appropriate)
};
options {
    ...
    allow-recursion { trustednets; };
};
```

Another option is to use views; this may suit DNS servers open to the public and also used by client systems, though is more complicated:

```
acl trustednets {
    ...  # as above
};
view favoredclients {
    match-clients      { trustednets; };
    match-destinations { trustednets; };
    recursion yes;
    zone ...  # zones probably best done via include
};
view thewashedmasses {
    recursion no;
    # https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-0550.html
    rate-limit {
            responses-per-second 5;
            window 5;
    };
    zone ...  # best done via include (because duplicated here)
};
```